# Find the SUM of two values from two different tables using PDO

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax, pdo

Hi_I’m trying to find the SUM of two separate values in two separate tables in my database using PDO but I’m having some trouble with it.

I have two tables: “balance” and “reward”.

“balance” has these two fields: user_id & g_balance.

“reward” has these two fields: user_id & rewards.

I’m trying to find out what the sum of balance.g_balance and reward.rewards is, and then have my PHP file echo the result back to my Javascript function.

The function sends the user’s id number to the PHP file by an AJAX POST.

```
<?php

$servername = "myservername";
$username = "myusername";
$password = "mypassword";
$dbname = "mydbname";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    // set the PDO error mode to exception
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT (SELECT g_balance FROM balance WHERE user_id = :userid) + (SELECT rewards FROM reward WHERE user_id = :userid)");
    $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
    $userid = $_POST['userid'];
    $stmt->execute();

    while($row=$stmt->fetch()){
        echo $result;
}}

catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;

?>
```

This code isn’t working, I’m not sure if just adding `+` between two separate select statements is the correct method to achieve what I want, and even if it is, might there be a better/more elegant way of doing this? Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: You'll have to perform 2 queries and then do the sum of the two values. Unless you have the tables setup to where you can join them and pull them both that way.

Comment: Hi @Skewled thanks for your comment, I am able to perform joins on my database, I'm unsure what type of join and syntax to use here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your error was the undefined variable `$userid`, and using the same variable to two `bindParam()` I used a JOIN feel. Free to try it; I haven't. Hope it helps.

```
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
        // set the PDO error mode to exception
        $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT b.g_balance + a.rewards  as Sum FROM reward a, balance b WHERE a.user_id = :userid AND b.user_id = a.user_id");
         $userid = $_POST['userid'];
         $stmt->bindParam(':userid', $userid);
        $stmt->execute();
        while($row=$stmt->fetch()){
            echo $row['Sum'];
    }
}

    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $conn = null;
```

Comment: Hi @elias-nicolas thanks for your reply, I don't understand what you mean by the variable being undefined, it's defined here: `` $userid = $_POST['userid'];``  the id is sent to the php file by an ajax post contained in a javascript function.

Comment: You are using it before is define. If you define it after you use it, it's undefined. Did you try the code? Is pretty simple, if you read it.

Comment: I made the changes you suggested but it's returning a blank result in the console (I have the Javascript set to console.log the response from the php). It's not showing any errors in the syntax so I'm unsure of what's wrong, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I corrected the code. It was echoing `$result` instead of `$row` So, now it should work.

Comment: Hi, it was returning the word ``Array`` so I needed to change it to state the row being echoed so I had to change it to ``echo $row['Sum'];`` it's working now so I'm marking your answer as correct, thanks for your time!